Xelatex: missing character, but character is present in the font file (tbsp)
I am writing a paper on Latex, using Xelatex for compilation. Whenever i build, i get these errors in my output:
Latexmk: ====Undefined refs and citations with line #s in .tex file:
  Missing character: There is no   in font CMU Serif Roman/OT:script=latn;languag
  Missing character: There is no   in font CMU Serif Roman/OT:script=latn;language=FRA;mapping=tex-text;!

However, i opened my font file in an editor (CMU Serif Roman) and i can see the character exists in the font file.
Here is the start of my main.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}[
  Path = ./fonts/,
  UprightFont={cmunrm},
  BoldFont={cmunbx},
  ItalicFont={cmunti},
  BoldItalicFont={cmunbi},
  Mapping = tex-text, % Ensures proper mapping for LaTeX characters
  Ligatures = TeX % Handles LaTeX-specific ligatures
]
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}[
  Path = ./fonts/,
  UprightFont = {cmunss},
  BoldFont = {cmunsx}
]

\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}[
  Path = ./fonts/,
  UprightFont = {cmuntt},
  BoldFont = {cmuntb},
  ItalicFont = {cmunti},
  BoldItalicFont = {cmuntx}
]

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{CMU Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{CMU Sans Serif}
\babelfont{tt}{CMU Typewriter Text}

The dreaded character is U+202F : NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE [NNBSP]
Can i do something about it?
Thanks

There is no U+202F in CMU Serif. Replace that by something else in your input, e.g. \,

I swore that i saw it, i edited the font with some online tool and i managed to it. But you're probably right, i ended up using egreg's solution. Thank you!

Make the character into a command that produces a thin space, if U+202F doesn't exist in the font.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

\newfontfamily{\oldstandard}{Old Standard}

\newunicodechar{^^^^202f}{\iffontchar\font"202F \char"202F \else\,\fi}

\begin{document}

A B

\textsf{A B}

{\oldstandard A B}

\end{document}


